# ALEXNET and LSTM as last layer features size issue

Tags: pytorch, lstm, image-classification

I have a set of mp4 videos where each have category label (15 classes in total). I am trying to implement ALEXNET and LASTM on top of it. I am getting an error when ALexnet output is passed into LSTM. Appreciate any recommendation or help

```
import cv2
import os
import json
import ast
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
from torchsummary import summary
from torchvision import models, transforms
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score


def create_frames_labels_array(labels_file='train_labels.txt', video_directory = '../data/vig_train/', num_frames = 15):
    # Load and preprocess data
    labels = []
    video_data = []

    frames_list = []  # Store all frames as a list
    labels_list = []  # Store corresponding labels

    with open(labels_file, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            video_name, label = line.strip().split(',')
            labels_list.append(int(label))
            video_path = os.path.join(video_directory, video_name)

            if '.DS_Store' in video_path:
                continue

            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

            frames = []

            for j in range(num_frames):
                frame_idx = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) * j / num_frames)
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if not ret:
                    break
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
                frame = frame / 255.0
                frames.append(frame)

            while len(frames) < num_frames:
                frames.append(frames[-1])

            frames_list.append(frames)

    # Convert the lists to NumPy arrays
    frames_array = np.array(frames_list)
    labels_array = np.array(labels_list)

    return frames_array, labels_array

train_frames_array, train_labels_array = create_frames_labels_array(labels_file='../visually-indicated-sounds/models/train_labels.txt', video_directory = '../visually-indicated-sounds/data/vig_train/', num_frames = 15)
display(train_frames_array.shape)
display(train_labels_array.shape)

(800, 15, 224, 224, 3)
(800,)
```

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models

# Define a function to apply transformations to frames (required for AlexNet)
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

alexnet_model = models.alexnet(pretrained=False, num_classes=15)
num_classes = 15  
alexnet_model.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(4096, num_classes)

class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()  # Use the correct class name in super()

        # Rest of your initialization code here
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Reshape the input to (batch_size * num_frames, num_channels, height, width)
        batch_size, num_frames, num_channels, height, width = x.size()
        x = x.view(batch_size * num_frames, num_channels, height, width)
    
        # Initialize hidden and cell states
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
    
        # Forward pass through the LSTM
        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
    
        # Get the output of the last time step
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out


# Initialize the LSTM model
input_size = 4096  # The output feature size of AlexNet
hidden_size = 512  # You can adjust this as needed
num_layers = 2  # You can adjust this as needed
lstm_model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes)

class CombinedModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, alexnet, lstm):
        super(CombinedModel, self).__init__()
        self.alexnet = alexnet
        self.lstm = lstm


    def forward(self, frames):
        # Extract features using AlexNet
        features = self.alexnet(frames)
        
        # Pass through LSTM
        output = self.lstm(features)
    
        return output

# Combine AlexNet and LSTM
model = CombinedModel(alexnet_model, lstm_model)
print(model)
```

```
CombinedModel(
  (alexnet): AlexNet(
    (features): Sequential(
      (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))
      (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (3): Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2))
      (4): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (5): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (6): Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (8): Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (10): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (12): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
    (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(6, 6))
    (classifier): Sequential(
      (0): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
      (1): Linear(in_features=9216, out_features=4096, bias=True)
      (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (3): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
      (4): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
      (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=15, bias=True)
    )
  )
  (lstm): LSTMModel(
    (lstm): LSTM(4096, 512, num_layers=2, batch_first=True)
    (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=15, bias=True)
  )
)
```

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image

def vig_train_and_evaluate_model(combined_model, frames_array, labels_array, num_classes=15, num_epochs=100, batch_size=32):

    print(frames_array.shape)
    print(labels_array.shape)

    batch_size, num_frames, height, width, num_channels = frames_array.shape
    frames_tensor = frames_array.reshape((batch_size * num_frames, num_channels, height, width))

    frames_tensor = torch.tensor(frames_tensor, dtype=torch.float32)
    labels_array_new = [item for item in labels_array for _ in range(15)]
    labels_array_new = torch.tensor(labels_array_new, dtype=torch.long)

    # Create a TensorDataset
    data = TensorDataset(frames_tensor, labels_array_new)

    # Create a DataLoader
    data_loader = DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

    # Define a loss function and optimizer
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(combined_model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

    # Lists to store predictions and true labels
    class_names = ['Bark', 'Cattle_bovinae', 'Bleat', 'rooster', 'Churchbell', 'Thunderstorm', 'Racecar_autoracing', 'Railtransport', 'Helicopter', 'Firealarm', 'Hammer', 'Gunshot_gunfire', 'Fireworks', 'Splash,splatter', 'Spray']
    all_predictions = []
    all_labels = []

    best_accuracy = 0.0
    best_model_state = None

    # Training loop
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for frames, labels in data_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = combined_model(frames)  
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # Convert model outputs to class predictions
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)

            # Append the predictions and labels to the lists
            all_predictions.extend(predicted.tolist())
            all_labels.extend(labels.tolist())

        # Calculate the confusion matrix
        cm = confusion_matrix(all_labels, all_predictions)
        display(pd.DataFrame(cm, columns=class_names))

        # Calculate the accuracy rate
        accuracy = accuracy_score(all_labels, all_predictions)
        print(f"Accuracy Rate: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

        # Check if the current accuracy is better than the best accuracy
        if accuracy > best_accuracy:
            best_accuracy = accuracy
            best_model_state = combined_model.state_dict()  # Save the model state

    return best_accuracy, best_model_state


best_accuracy, best_model_state = vig_train_and_evaluate_model(model, train_frames_array, train_labels_array, num_classes=15, num_epochs=10, batch_size=32)

(800, 15, 224, 224, 3)
(800,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 best_accuracy, best_model_state = vig_train_and_evaluate_model(model, train_frames_array, train_labels_array, num_classes=15, num_epochs=10, batch_size=32)

Cell In[4], line 43, in vig_train_and_evaluate_model(combined_model, frames_array, labels_array, num_classes, num_epochs, batch_size)
     40 for frames, labels in data_loader:
     41     optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 43     outputs = combined_model(frames)  
     44     loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     45     loss.backward()

File ~/miniforge3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1518, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1516     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1517 else:
-> 1518     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1527, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1522 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1523 # this function, and just call forward.
   1524 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1525         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1526         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1527     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1529 try:
   1530     result = None

Cell In[3], line 62, in CombinedModel.forward(self, frames)
     59 features = self.alexnet(frames)
     61 # Pass through LSTM
---> 62 output = self.lstm(features)
     64 return output

File ~/miniforge3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1518, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1516     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1517 else:
-> 1518     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1527, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1522 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1523 # this function, and just call forward.
   1524 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1525         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1526         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1527     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1529 try:
   1530     result = None

Cell In[3], line 29, in LSTMModel.forward(self, x)
     27 def forward(self, x):
     28     # Reshape the input to (batch_size * num_frames, num_channels, height, width)
---> 29     batch_size, num_frames, num_channels, height, width = x.size()
     30     x = x.view(batch_size * num_frames, num_channels, height, width)
     32     # Initialize hidden and cell states

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 2)
```

This is failing here

```
    def forward(self, frames):
        # Extract features using AlexNet
        features = self.alexnet(frames)
        
        # Pass through LSTM
        output = self.lstm(features)
    
        return output
```

I have tried many changes including but did not work

```
    def forward(self, frames):
        # Extract features using AlexNet
        features = self.alexnet(frames)
        
        # Ensure features are 5D (batch_size, num_frames, num_channels, height, width)
        if features.dim() == 4:
            features = features.unsqueeze(1)  # Add an extra dimension for num_frames
        
        batch_size, num_frames, num_channels, height, width = features.size()
        features = features.view(batch_size, num_frames, num_channels * height * width)
        
        # Pass through LSTM
        output = self.lstm(features)

        return output
```